# TFS Show Latest on Top Level Folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I'm working with TFS for a bit now and my question is about a function in the Source Control Explorer.

A sample Folder Structure for my Project might be this:
Project/MyControllers/Controller.cs

I change something in the Controller.cs and I navigate to the folder "Project" inside my Source Control Explorer. There it says at the Column "Latest", yes. Which in my opinion isnt right, because i changed something inside the folder. When i navigate into "MyControllers" it says that my Controller.cs changed.

Is it somehow possible to see the "No" at the "Project" level?

I dont know if its important by my Visual Studio Version is 2017.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Even if you've changed something your code version is still latest till someone else checks-in a change that out-dates your local version.  What you're asking about are two different things.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it does not help me much.

Comment: Have you checked in Controller.cs when you naviagte the folder "Project"?

Comment: Yes i have. There i see the "No". But i dont want to navigate inside each Folder to see if there is a File that hasnt got the latest Version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct and excepted behave. The **Latest**  column is used to show the mapping status between your local file in workspace and the correspondingly server file. Which include value such as ***yes, no ,not download , not mapped***. It will not influence either subfolder or parent directory.

Only when the name of "Project" folder has changed such as "ProjectDone" by others and checked in, it will show the Latest status of Project with "No". This is a point to point mapping status.

And you don't have to always paying attention to the file is latest or not. In other words, you don't have to and can't make sure always working on the latest version.  When you working on a file and some others make same change during you local working. TFS will record the changes and let you solve conflicts when you perform the check in action.

Usually you just need to do a **get latest** of the workspace or top folder in the beginning  of the day of work on a project.

Comment: Okay thats an answer i can work with :) I didn't know it was mapped Point to Point. Then it sounds right, that he only registers changes in the folder name.