# What is in Latest column in Source Control Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

[image]

The value can be:

- Not downloaded
- Yes
- No

What do they mean? [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-source-control-explorer-manage-files-under-version-control) page (F1) is not very helpful and I have some problems to figure it out: it say `Yes` even if I get specific **not latest** version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That says your workspace contains not latest version.

The example with no latest version:

[image]

Latest version:

[image]

For a folder you can get "NO" for latest if it was renamed and you don`t update your workspace:

[image]

Comment: This answers the question. But I've asked a wrong question I am afraid. What I've observed happens with *branches* (same as folders). At your screenshot it say `Yes` for `Properties` folder. Now go inside, change something (add/delete file), go up and it will stay `Yes`. This is very confusing, unless it has a special use (e.g. changing folder name?). Can you produce `No` for folder? Can you explain the use of `Yes` for folder?

Comment: I`ve updated my answer. Your question also was considered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46031071/tfs-show-latest-on-top-level-folder